# Unable to cast object exception while using LINQ To Entities with LINQKit

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linqkit

I'm using **[LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)** to expand LINQ To Entities capabilities:

```
public Boolean IsMatched(Int32 age)
{
    return age > 18;
}

public IQueryable<Users> GetAllMatchedUsers(Func<Int32, Boolean> isMatched)
{
    return qry = _Context.Users.AsExpandable().Where(x => x.IsActive && isMatched(x.Age));
}
```

This code is used for **Entity Framework ORM** objects (_Context is **DbContext**, Users - is **DBSet**)

This code throws following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' to type
> 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'

Getting rid of `Func` and hardcoding `IsMatched` into `GetAllMatchedUsers` solves this problem. But I need to use `Func` to pass different selection criteria from Business Logic Layer to my Data Access Layer.

P. S. `IsMatched` is highly simplified realisation for example of course.

Comment: Are you also missing a parameter name in your code or is it just here?

Comment: Just here :) I've corrected my code sample..

Comment: Added some more info about what is _Context and Users are

Comment: Why do you use that `AsExpandable`? It seems redundant to me. Why the `Where` clause is not enough?

Comment: AsExpandable is LINQKit extention method. Without it enother exception is raised which tells me that LINQ to Entities doesn't suppert Invoke. I've expected AsExpandable  to solve this problem (as far as I understanded LINQKit documentation) - but I've failed and described my code here...

Answer (score 1):

With LinqKit you'll have to pass `Expression<Func<Int32, Boolean>> isMatched`

`Func<...>` is something that is compiled already to C# runtime.

`Expression<Func<...>>` is something that you can transfer as expression tree to SQL.